# Install all unmet dependencies in yarn

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dependencies, yarnpkg

There's error in my react app, it says:

```
    Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot find module 'eslint-scope' from '/home/path/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-eslint-7.11.0-aaf2d23a0b5f1d652a08edacea0c19f7fadc0b3b-integrity/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js'
```

Then I add eslint-scope to my dependencies with the following command:

```
    yarn add eslint-scope
```

But I found so much, unmet peer dependencies:

```
    warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.1.10" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.0.0".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@typescript-eslint/parser@^4.0.0".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-eslint@^10.0.0".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-flowtype@^5.2.0".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.0".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.3.1".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react@^7.20.3".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4.0.8".
```

When I tried install one of those, I found another unmet dependencies:

```
    warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.1.10" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.0.0".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@typescript-eslint/parser@^4.0.0".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-flowtype@^5.2.0".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.0".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.3.1".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react@^7.20.3".
    warning " > eslint-config-react-app@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4.0.8".
```

**can I install all of the unmeet dependencies automatically?**

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should try to find out why `eslint-scope` is needed by running this command `yarn why eslint-scope`.

If you still think it's needed then you should know that peer dependencies by default are not installed anymore. [You can read more about it here](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/#using-peer-dependencies). In NPM V7 peerDependencies are [installed automatically again](https://github.blog/2020-10-13-presenting-v7-0-0-of-the-npm-cli/).

For now you should try using the [install-peerdeps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peerdeps) package `npx install-peerdeps -Y eslint-scope`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is by using the `check-peer-dependencies` npm package ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-peer-dependencies))

example:

```
yarn install --no-progress --non-interactive \
&& npx check-peer-dependencies --yarn --install \
```

In case that your are experience some issues like "Unable to find a version", you can do something like that:

```
yarn install --no-progress --non-interactive \
(npx check-peer-dependencies --yarn --install || true)
```

note: `check-peer-dependencies` (version: 4.2.0) will install the peer dependency, but from some reason it will throw an error.